# Accessing $rootScope property in module.run after initializing with ng-init

Tags: angularjs

So I set a rootScope variable by:

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-init="$root.number=10">
```

And then I want in the module.run method to access the $rootScope.number but I get undefined. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time `.run()` executes, the application is not yet parsed by Angular.
You could use **[`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout)** to access the property as soon as everything is rendered, by which time the DOM will have been fully parsed by Angular:

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-init="number=42">

angular.module('App', [])
.run(function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function () {
        alert($rootScope.number);
    });
});
```